# How to distribute a ROS package without sharing the sources

Tags: package, share, ros, software-distribution

Is there a way to distribute a ROS package without sharing the sources?

I just want the user to be able to run the ROS nodes without dependencies problems.

I know ROS is an open-source project, but I am not allowed to share the code.

Answer (score 12):

**Solution 1:**

In your package CMakelists.txt, add the install directives. It goes like this :

```
install( TARGETS
    #list of nodes
    DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION}
)

install(TARGETS
    #list of shared libraries
    ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
    LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
)

install(FILES 
  #list of necessary files (xml...)
  DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_SHARE_DESTINATION}
)

install(DIRECTORY 
  include/${PROJECT_NAME}/
  DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_INCLUDE_DESTINATION}
  PATTERN ".svn" EXCLUDE
  PATTERN ".git" EXCLUDE
)
```

Using

```
 $ catkin_make 
 $ catkin_make install
```

you can create the binaries needed for execution without sharing the code. This will create another folder `/install` in addition to the usual `/devel` and `/build` in your catkin workspace.

Note : You can specify the install folder using :

```
 $ catkin_make -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=path/to/folder install
```

Just make sure that `the binaries need to be compiled for the correct architecture that the other computer has` and any dependencies you do not have in your workspace when you invoke catkin_make need to also be installed by the other part before being used.

Now that you have the `/install` folder, just zip & send it.

Now, the essential part would be adding the install/setup.bash to your the other machine `.bashrc`, or ROS won't find the distributed pacakges.

```
$ echo "source ~/catkin_ws/install/setup.bash" >> ~/.bashrc
```

See [here](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/commands/catkin_make) for more information.

**Solution 2:**

you can have bloom generate you a deb-src and then you can compile that and distrbute the .deb file, ion the other machine, you can install it with `dpkg -i`. This could be done by following this part of [the pre-release tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/bloom/Tutorials/PrereleaseTest#bloom.2BAC8-Tutorials.2BAC8-PrereleaseTest.2BAC8-indigo.Perform_the_pre-release_locally).

Comment: Will this enter in conflict with the environment that was setup on the other machine already?

Comment: Well, only if the same package is already existing in the other machine, I think...

Comment: How exactly do I run the nodes on the other machine? There is no package that contains the nodes, so I can't use rosrun. They are all in the install folder (sorry for late reply, only coming back to this now)

Comment: I updated the answer ! I took that step for granted... Cheers

Comment: This answer was exactly what I was looking for! Thank you. It looks like there is nothing CMake cannot do :)

Comment: I created a basic publisher package.  I use "catkin_make install" to create an install file and after I delete the src file. Yes, It works but if I delete the build and devel file, it does not work. Other things I send install file to the new workspace but it does not work. How can I overcome this problem? I get this error **[rosrun] Couldn't find executable named publisher below /home/username/catkin_ws/install/share/beginner_tutorials**

Answer (score 0):

I could not resolve this with either `catkin_make install` or bloom. Fortunately, I was allowed to share the hard disk where the workspace was, so I merely had to create .pyc files from my .py scripts and make them executable.