# How to use ROS package without source file on another pc?

Tags: cmake, build, ros, catkin

I want to use my package but it won't has got source code files. I try to a way, Way is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40042674/12158653). So, I create to **install** file using **catkin_make install** and after I  delete src file. It is running, OK but if I delete **devel** file, It is not work.

In short, I can say: I just want to send my package without src file to another computer and run it.

How to overcome this problem?

Comment: What problem did you encounter? Please show a [mre] including the full error message

Comment: I get this error : **[rosrun] Couldn't find executable named publisher below /home/username/catkin_ws/install/share/beginner_tutorials** @AlanBirtles

Answer (score 0):

I forget to install **bin** files.
it have to be added on CMakeLists.txt.

```
install(TARGETS your_node RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION})
```